# Custom caption for lstset to use in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions

I would like to use the functionality of figure captions (that can have two captions: one for table of contents and one for the caption below/above the figure) with my custom `filecode` environment. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=C++,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=4pt,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  moredelim=[s][\color{gray}]{@}{\ },
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}

\newenvironment{filecode}[1][]
  {\vspace{1ex} \minipage[0.5\textheight]{\linewidth}% \begin{filecode}[#1]
   \lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\footnotesize,#1}}
  {\endminipage \vspace{1em}}% \end{filecode}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecode}[label=lst:code,caption=Very long and frustrating caption that noone want to see before this page]
  \lstinputlisting{main.cpp}
\end{filecode}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
caption={[Short caption]Very long and frustrating caption that noone want to see before this page}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=C++,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=4pt,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape,
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  moredelim=[s][\color{gray}]{@}{\ },
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=2
}

\newenvironment{filecode}[1][]
  {\vspace{1ex} \minipage[0.5\textheight]{\linewidth}% \begin{filecode}[#1]
   \lstset{basicstyle=\fontfamily{pcr}\footnotesize,#1}}
  {\endminipage \vspace{1em}}% \end{filecode}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{filecode}[label=lst:code,caption={[Short caption]Very long and frustrating caption that noone want to see before this page}]
  \lstinputlisting{main.cpp}
\end{filecode}

\end{document}
```

[image]